# Go "exec.Command" of tcpdump not doing anything

Tags: go

I am attempting to run the following code in Go.  I have tried both of the following ways:

```
out, err := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "tcpdump -i ens0 host 192.168.1.100 -F ./testfile").Output()
fmt.Println(string(out))           // Prints nothing
fmt.Println(err)                   // exit status 1
```

I have also tried replacing `sh` with `/bin/bash`.
I have also tried the following, with and without `sh` as the first argument:

```
out, err := exec.Command("tcpdump", "-i", "ens0", "host", "192.168.1.100", "-F", "./testfile").Output()
fmt.Println(string(out))           // Prints nothing
fmt.Println(err)                   // exit status 1
```

None of this is working.  Can someone see what I am doing wrong?  I have also tried this go package `"github.com/kami-zh/go-capturer"` to read stderr and again it prints nothing.

Normally I have to use `sudo` to execute `tcpdump` from shell, so I build the go binary and execute it as root user.

Comment: The exit status is 1, what does stderr say?

Comment: I attempted to read stderr like this and got nothing.
`out := capturer.CaptureStderr(func() {
 exec.Command("tcpdump", "-i", "enp0s31f6", "host", "192.168.1.180", "-F", folderPath+pcapName).Output()
})
fmt.Println(out)`

Comment: Don’t try to put code in the comments. I don’t know how that’s supposed to capture stderr, since it does not touch the command stderr in any way.

Comment: By default, `tcpdump` just keeps on running, gathering data forever. The `Output()` function collects all of the output, waiting for the program to terminate. So it waits forever, accumulating more and more output (if there is any more), waiting, and waiting, and waiting some more. When will it stop waiting? Never. To make `Output()` finish and return the collected output, you have to make `tcpdump` stop running, finish printing its output, and exit. Of course, if your filter expression is bad, it will never start running at all, and thus have no output.

Comment: In this case, I suspect the filter in your file is bad, or the file itself (`./testfile`) is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, i am not sure if there is any specific command like -F available in tcp dump,
If you want to capture plain output of the tcp dump , you can direct the output to file using `> file` . The -w option is for wireshark/tcpdump format , to read and display

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "sudo tcpdump -i <eth> host <ip> -w ./testfile")
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Thanks, @torek, the -c option can be used with tcpdump to exit after capturing n packets

```
 cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "sudo tcpdump -i ens33 -c 100 host localhost -w ./testfile")
 err := cmd.Run()
 if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
 }
```

The other way is to use `cmd.Start`

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "sudo tcpdump -i ens33 -c 100 host localhost -w ./testfile")
err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Printf("Waiting for command to finish...")
err = cmd.Wait()
log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
```

The tcpdump command continue to run infinitely if you use cmd.run without -c option with tcpdump cmd.So you can't see if you put print statement after cmd.Run() call, the reason being the exec.Command failed is, it just work the same way on how it works from the cli, so if you need sodo in front for it , you should put it in command as well or run it from the root user.

Comment: You might want `-c` and a packet count here, so that the whole thing will terminate. Or, one could use `cmd.Start`, without redirecting the output to a file, and collect the output as it comes, although this starts to get a bit more complicated.

Comment: @torek yes , -c work too and `cmd.Start` will run the command and dont wait for it to finish. let me update the answer with this input as well that will improve the answers and whoever looking at this .